# How can I copy feature in ArcMap to a specified location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, copy

In ArcMap you can use the copy and paste on the standard toolbar or use the Copy Features tool on the Advanced Editing toolbar to copy the selected feature. But the former can only copy a feature to the same location (duplicate on top of), while the latter can be copied to the specific location of the mouse but cannot use the snap function so you cannot copy the feature to an *exact* location.

Although both methods can achieve precise positioning by feature movement after it is copied, with a great number of copies more time per operation is required. I wanted to know if there is a way to achieve in one step an exact copy of the feature to a specified location.

Comment: So far as I know, there's no way to do what you want in a single step. I just copy in place and then drag/snap. Particularly with polygons this is usually necessary anyway, at least for me. Since you're usually trying to get a polygon corner to snap to another, you have to move the feature control point out to a vertex (holding ctrl) to get the snap location to the right place. Of course, if you're just centering a polygon on a point or something you wouldn't need to do this. BTW, *graphics* and *features* are two very different things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I using that way you said now, but if I want to copy the many different features, each time to move the control point also would be a bit tedious, so I wanted to know if there is any better way to achieve.
I think that if this tool can specify the base point and the destination point replication, It may be more convenient to use.